# Redefining an Enum/ Global Enum Value in C

Tags: c, enums, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

In a previous question I asked, I found out I had to use an enum for whatever reason to define my values in the following source code:

```
enum { key0_buffer = 0};
void process_tuple(Tuple *t)
{
    //Get key
    int key = t->key;

    //Get integer value, if present
    int value = t->value->int32;

    //Decide what to do
    switch(key) {
    case key_0:
        enum {key0_buffer = value};      
        break;
    };
}
...
static  WeatherAppDataPoint s_data_points[] = 
{
    {
        ...
        .high = key0_buffer,
    },   
};
```

In this code, meant to run on the Pebble Watch(cloud pebble.com), value comes from a separate JS app running on a phone and then receives that value. However, as seen here I want to turn that integer into an enumerator(reason is here: [initializer element not constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158010/initializer-element-not-constant)). The code spits the following errors:

```
    ../src/app_data.c:120:5: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement
../src/app_data.c:120:11: error: enumerator value for 'key0_buffer' is not an integer constant
../src/app_data.c:109:9: error: variable 'value' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
```

How can I convert an integer into an enumerator?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Looks like you're trying to initialize a global static variable with something that apparently will only be set once a function is called (i.e. at runtime). Enums are constants, you can't change their value.

Comment: @Mat Thanks a lot. That helped, I think I have to modify the structure of this code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows some fundamental misunderstandings of how C works. For example the enum in the switch case does not make sense at all. The enum declares values at compile time, while a switch is used during runtime for control flow.

You should find a beginners book on C and start with some basic examples.

Comment: Yes, its true, im more of a JS, Python and Rails kinda person, working with the more higher level languages. The book on C I have never talked about Enums... But thanks for that advice anyway, I'm probably going to buy a better book.